# Proposition or open sentence?

Tags: logic

I have a doubt.

When I write "If x is a natural number, x + 1 is also", am I writing a (true) proposition or am I writing an open sentence in the free variable x?

Comment: Formally, it is an *open* formula: $\text {Nat(x)} \to \text {Nat(x+1)}$. Obviously, what we mean is $\forall x \ (\text {Nat(x)} \to \text {Nat(x+1)})$.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that depends on the context.  You would *probably* be making a universal claim, as in Mees's answer, but it is also possible that you say this in a context where $x$ was used to refer to some specific object, to which the name $x$ was given.

Comment: You would hope that you could find a different letter than $x$ - but who knows? +1

Comment: @MikeMathMan Or a different name altogether, like 'object of mystery' :)

Answer (score 1):

It's a proposition. Formally, it would be written as $\forall x(x \in \mathbb N \to x + 1 \in \mathbb N)$.

Comment: Does the universal appear because it is a conditional?  For example "$x$ is a natural number and $x+1$ is also." looks like an open sentence with free variable $x$.